# Where can I find widgets to replace Windows Sidebar gadgets?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, widgets

Now security advisors are calling for disabling the Windows Sidebar entirely.

Are there stand-alone apps that work with both Windows Vista and 7?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "stand-along apps". Could you clarify that please?

Comment: Yahoo Widgets was one, but is discontinued now.

Comment: Windows sidebar is safe, its the gadgets you download that are not, just be careful where you download them. " Gadgets installed from untrusted sources can harm your computer and can access your computer's files, show you objectionable content, or change their behavior at any time."...https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/advisory/2719662